# whenever am trying to select multiple columns from my mysql table my apache is being reset

Tags: php, mysqli, apache2.2

let's assume i have a table with five columns like `TABLE(a,b,c,d,e)`
now if i try to fetch multiple columns like

```
$sql="select a,b,c from TABLE";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql );
if (!$result)
{
 echo "something wrong";
 exit();
}
and so on................
```

**note there is not any wrong in rest code.because the code is working properly when 1 column is selected**

while multiple columns are selected it's causing error ::

```
[Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.]
```

it particularly happening when only multiple columns are selected.***

> i have been told it's my apache config problem ...if so the can you
>   tell me how to fix it??

---

Comment: The value assigned to `$sql` needs to be quoted. Also, what do you see in the the Apache error log and PHP error log files?

Comment: tha's the typing mistake while typing in this forum..in my actual code i didn't make that mistake..see latest edit